# How can I implement a function that returns a generic constrained by an integral type?

Tags: rust

How can I implement a function such as the following, where `T` is an integral type?

```
fn get_vec<T>() -> Vec<T>
{
    let vec: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
    let n: i32 = 5;
    let n_as_t = n as T;
    vec.push(n_as_t);
    vec
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that generics are type-checked *prior* to being expanded; this means that the compiler must verify that `n as T` (where `n` is an `i32`) is valid for all possible `T`.  It isn't.

What you *want* is to, using a trait, constrain `T` to types which can be cast from an `i32`.  Somewhat tragically, this trait does not exist.

The closest analog is probably `std::convert::From`, but it doesn't implement such basic conversions and you can't provide them yourself.  There used to be some traits that dealt in converting to/from primitive integer types, but I believe they were removed prior to the 1.0 cleanup.

At which point, you're basically on your own.  You need to roll a trait that expresses this conversion, then implement it for the types you care about.  So, you could use a trait such as:

```
trait FromI32 {
    fn from_i32(v: i32) -> Self;
}
```

then change the function to use `<T: FromI32>` and `FromI32::from_i32(n)` instead of `n as T`.

If there are more than a few types for which you want to implement said trait, a simple macro should cut down on the repetition.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I'd rep you if I could:).